# Get the last letter and everything after it in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a few hundred thousand strings that are laid out like the following

```
AX23784268B2
LJ93842938A1
MN39423287S
IY289383N2
```

With PHP I'm racking my brain how to return `B2`, `A1`, `S`, and `N2`.

Tried all sorts of substr, strstr, strlen manipulation and am coming up short.

```php
substr('MN39423287S', -2); ?> // returns 7S, not S
```

Comment: Is it always just 2 chars, I doubt it if there are few,000

Comment: @KenLee nope, that would return 7S on the 3rd one. I'm trying to get the last letter and anything after it. That one should just return "S".

Comment: @RiggsFolly the third one down, would just be "S" since its the last letter and anything after it. So it's always either 1 or 2 characters. Either 1 letter and 1 number, or just 1 letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simpler regexp than the other answer:

```
preg_match('/[A-Z][^A-Z]*$/', $token, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

`[A-Z]` matches a letter, `[^A-Z]` matches a non-letter. `*` makes the preceiding pattern match any number of times (including 0), and `$` matches the end of the string.

So this matches a letter followed by any number of non-letters at the end of the string.

`$matches[0]` contains the portion of the string that the entire regexp matched.

Answer (score 1):

There's many way to do this.
One example would be a regex

```php
<?php

$regex = "/.+([A-Z].?+)$/";

$tokens = [
'AX23784268B2',
'LJ93842938A1',
'MN39423287S',
'IY289383N2',
];

foreach($tokens as $token)
{
    preg_match($regex, $token, $matches);
    var_dump($matches[1]);  
    // B2, A2, S, N2
}
```

How the regex works;

```
.+       - any character except newline
(        - create a group
  [A-Z]  - match any A-Z character
  .?+    - also match any characters after it, if any
)        - end group
$        - match the end of the string
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to decipher, thank you! Nothing was coming up for "get everything including and after last letter", just a lot of getting everything after the last comma or slash but not the entire alphabet. Perfect

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by explaining how the regex works, so that it could be adapted to other variations of the problem. e.g. someone looking for "after the last digit" or "before the first letter" could use this as a starting point with some hints about what the pattern means.

Comment: @IMSoP I will explain the regex later, after cooking :))